# Angular 11 fill input in HTML

Tags: html, angular, angular11

I'm facing a problem, mainly I cannot fill a value in input but in the HTML. I searched but nothing seems to work. I tried value, `(value)`, `[(value)]`, `"k.bag.ConstructionYear"`, `"{{k.bag.ConstructionYear}}"` and other combinations and nothing seems to work.

mycomponent.html

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="{
    // other stuff
    firstStepState: firstStepState$ | async
  } as o"
>
  //........
  <ng-container *ngIf="{
          bag : testService.getData(o.firstStepState.value1, o.firstStepState.value2) | async
        } as k">

    <ng-container *ngIf="k.bag !== undefined && k.bag !== null">
    {{k.bag.ConstructionYear}} // <-- this is showing 

    <input
        type="text"
        name="constructionYear"
        formControlName="constructionYear"
        id="constructionYear"
        data-test="constructionYear"
        placeholder=""
        [value]="k.bag.ConstructionYear" <-- this is the problem
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="constructionYear"
    formControlName="constructionYear"
    id="constructionYear"
    data-test="constructionYear"
    placeholder=""
    [(ngModel)]="k.bag.ConstructionYear"
/>
```

for binding with your data

Comment: Don't mix reactive form models with template form models. i.e. the `formControlName` and the `ngModel` attribute should not both be on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

by assigning `formControlName="constructionYear"` to the input, you delegate value control of this input to your formControl. from this point of time you should update the logical form from your ts code whenever you want, not the value of the input. for example through method `control.setValue(newValue)`